# Copy every 4 column and paste in another sheet Microsoft excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. Actually, my objective is to copy every 4 columns with 5 rows one after one to a new worksheet named `USD`.

Below is my code but it is not working in a loop.

```
Sub CopyColumns()
    Range("A5:D9").Select '**I want to add 4 columns till the end of last column with data**
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Test").Select
    Sheets.Add.Name = "USD"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Test").Select

    **'Sceond loop should be like below**
    Range("E5:H9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("USD").Select
    Range("A6").Select '**I need to paste data after last row used every time**
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a loop and a way to move your selection. For loop look up While because you dont know exactly how many times you want to repeat the code and for variables you can use Offset or directly put them into Cells to specify the selection.

```
Sub CopyColumns()
Dim iCycle As Long

iCycle = 0

Sheets.Add.Name = "USD"
Sheets("Test").Select

While Range("A5").Offset(0, iCycle * 4).Value <> "" 'checks if there are any values left to be copied

    Range("A5:D9").Offset(0, iCycle * 4).Copy 'Offset moves whole selection by 4 columns to the right every time
    Sheets("USD").Select
    Sheets("USD").Range(Cells(1 + iCycle * 5, 1), Cells(1 + iCycle * 5, 4)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Cells can also be used to specify selection based on variable
    Sheets("Test").Select

    iCycle = iCycle + 1
Wend

End Sub
```